# Django User Profile - default value depend on chosen User

Tags: django

I want to create Profile extending User model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    operatorId = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        default= 'O'+str(user.id), #get user id
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
    )
```

Want to add `operatorId` which depends on userId chosen (operator id i O and user.id as a string). How to get current user id? basically, I need to change default every-time I change user. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should override `save` method

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    operatorId = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.operatorId = 'O'+str(self.user.id) # set operatorId here
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

note that overriding `save` has a limitation:

> Unfortunately, there isn’t a workaround when creating or updating
>   objects in bulk, since none of save(), pre_save, and post_save are
>   called.

check django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) for more info